# Is message property on Error propertyIsEnumerable?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, ecmascript-5

What is the correct result of the following? Do any of the ECMA standards specify this? My current Chrome 14.0.835.186m thinks `false` and Firefox 3.6.22 thinks `true`.

```
(new Error()).propertyIsEnumerable("message")
```

This is extra annoying because Chrome used to think `true` as well, and now I have broken code because of this change.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  I'd be interested in seeing a use case or example of how you're using `propertyIsEnumerable` on `Error` objects.

Comment: The code actually was trying to copy fields from an Error object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`propertyIsEnumerable` doesn't return true for 'built-ins' like:

`Error.prototype.message` or `Array.prototype.length`

Enumerable properties are those set directly on the object itself as defined in section 15.2.4.7 of ECMA 262, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

For example:

```
> var arr = [];
> arr.propertyIsEnumerable("length")
false
> arr.kudos = 55;
55
> arr.propertyIsEnumerable("kudos")
true
> var err = new Error("some message");
> err.propertyIsEnumerable("message")
false
> err.Something = { };
{}
> err.propertyIsEnumerable("Something")
true
```

the `propertyIsEnumerable` method is meant to determine what can be used in a `for..in` loop.

For example:

```
> for(var key in arr) { console.log(key); }
kudos
> for(var key in err) { console.log(key); }
Something
```

Are you using `propertyIsEnumerable` instead of `hasOwnProperty`?

```
> err.hasOwnProperty("message")
true
> arr.hasOwnProperty("length")
true
```

Here are some other examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable

My assumption for the reason these used to work is that these browsers are ramping up for ECMAScript 5 compliance.

Edit:

If you *need* all properties including non-enumerable properties, you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`.  Here's an example that copies non-enumerable properties to another object.

```
> var err = new Error("Some message");
> var copy = { };
> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err).forEach(function(key) {
... copy[key] = err[key];
... });
> copy
{ stack: 'Error: Some message\n    at repl:1:11\n    at Interface.<anonymous> (r
epl.js:168:22)\n    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)\n    at Interface._onLin
e (readline.js:153:10)\n    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)\n    at Inter
face._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)\n    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:
73:12)\n    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:70:17)\n    at onKeypress (tty_win32.j
s:46:10)',
  message: 'Some message',
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined }
> copy instanceof Error
false
> err instanceof Error
true
```

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#section_2

Comment: Thank you, this finally makes some sense. So there will be no way to discover properties of the built-ins using `for .. in``?

Comment: I added a short example of how to do this using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.  Called on its own, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` will return an array of property names.  The part I added enumerates that array and copies the property of the `Error` object to a new non-Error object.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find in the `ECMAScript 5` spec where it is required either way *(doesn't mean it isn't there)*, but it does appear to be configurable, so you can do this:

```
Object.defineProperty( Error.prototype,'message',{enumerable:true});

console.log( Error.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('message') ); // true
```

or this:

```
var err = new Error('a message');

Object.defineProperty( err,'message',{enumerable:true});

console.log( err.propertyIsEnumerable("message") );  // true
```

Comment: I'd go with the first example so all `Error` objects have an enumerable property.

Comment: Check the last paragraph of the chapter 15 [Standard Built-in ECMAScript Objects](http://es5.github.com/#x15) section: *"Every other property described in this clause has the attributes `{ [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }` unless otherwise specified."* :-)

Comment: @CMS: *Thank you* for pointing me to that! I've run a few tests, and there's an odd behavior in Chrome 14. If you `var err=new Error('the msg');`, the `err` will have its own property `"message"`, which is *non-enumerable*. But if you then make `Error.prototype.message` enumerable, the `err` that we *previously* created still shows `.propertyIsEnumerable('message'); //false`, but strangely, it will be included in the enumeration of `err`. Anyway, [here's the test](http://jsfiddle.net/y8XTr/) that I put together if you're interested.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ: You're welcome. Yeah, that's clearly a bug (it remembered me the IE<=8 `{DontEnum}` bug, but with the opposite behavior), check this simpler test case: http://jsfiddle.net/cmsalvado/Gaaau/

Comment: @CMS: Yep, looks like the `for-in` statement is including the prototyped *enumerable* `foo` even though it is shadowed by the local *non-enumerable* `foo`, but then to make things more confusing, it is retrieving the value from the *non-enumerable* one. [If I update your example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaaau/1/) to add an enumerable to each object, sure enough, the local enumerable is first, the prototyped *(non-shadowed)* enumerable comes next, then finally the *shadowed* enumerable comes last *(showing that it is on the `prototype`)*, but it gives the value of the property that is shadowing it.

Comment: Looks like it's a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=705).

Answer (score 0):

The correct result is false because the `message` property of `Error` is inherited (I think from the prototype).

Comment: You are right, I did not realize `propertyIsEnumerable` and `for (var field in object) {}` are different, but they are. I am interested in the latter actually. It still does not enumerate through `message` field on `Error`.

Comment: What difference are you referring to? `propertyIsEnumerable` returns false if the type of the object containing the passed-in property is built-in, just as that same property would not be enumerated in a for/in loop.

Comment: The difference is that `propertyIsEnumerable` returns `false` for a property that is inherited via a prototype while that property still can be enumerated on. For example: `function f(){this.x=1}; function g(){}; g.prototype=new f(); var x = new g(); for (var f in x) {console.log(f)}; x.propertyIsEnumerable("x")`